# Access - Add 2 Option Groups to an Option Group

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am creating a form in Access 2007 that has two option group with two radio buttons in each. I previously had a button that used the two radio boxes to populate some data.

[image: My Radio Buttons]

However, I've decided that it would be a better to just have it update as soon as a new option is chosen. So I thought what could be easier than just drawing a new option group around *Shift* and *Line* and use the before or after update event for the code. So I created it and set everything to transparent.

However I'm having trouble (I assume) with adding the two option groups to this new option group because the after update event is not triggering. I tried cutting and pasting Shift and Line into the new Option group, but that doesn't seem to work.

Any idea how I can get these two sets of radio buttons into one event trigger?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried creating two events (one for each) and letting both call the same handling function?

Comment: I've considered doing so, but I'd prefer to keep it simple as one event. If I can't figure this out, I'll probably do just that. But I'd rather know if there is an easier solution to quickly use in the future...and I hate when I have I can't figure out something.